# Angularjs : i want to insert value to input field on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type='text' ng-model="mydata"  />
  <span ng-bind="$parent.$eval(mydata)"></span> <br>

  <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click =" mydata = button">
    {{button}}</button>
```

Here i have array of buttons and when i click one button it will be inserted in input field without removing previous value.

Comment: is buttons an array of strings?

Comment: NO all are numbers

Comment: what about ng-click="mydata = +button;" then?

Comment: not working ? i inspect element and it is `ng-click=" mydata = +button"`

Comment: it should be button value   `ng-click=" mydata = 1"`   where 1 is button value

Comment: Do you mean inserted in cursor position or simply appended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that ng-repeat creates new scope. You need to do `ng-click="$parent.mydata=button"`

check it out here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yrIR6L0tDBI1IaCkaKYw?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model="mydata"  />
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click="$parent.mydata = $parent.mydata.toString() + button">{{button}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great but it is removing previous value ..it means 1 then 2 then3 and so on .. without replace any value

Comment: Updated the answer by adding `ng-click ="$parent.mydata = $parent.mydata.toString() + button"`

Comment: need help plz, How i remove one by one... on a button click

Comment: Martin help  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831737/how-to-reset-incresed-value-to-its-initial-value-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

sometimes with multi level scopes the primary types have issues. 
So while changing also try using $parent.mydata if mydata is on immediate parent (or $parent.$parent.mydata and so on..) OR use an object on parent controller with myData as a property so that you can access it from below child controller like "objectName.mydata"