# How to reset incresed Value to it's initial value in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
$scope.count = 23;  // this is the initial value


<button ng-click = "count = count + 1"> Increase</button>

{{count}}   //Here Value will increase
```

And count value changed...

Q1.My question is How do i reset that value to 23 and display ? OR store that value in a variable.

Q2. Suppose count value increased from 23 to 29 by clicking. And how to get that value 29.

Comment: You might mean one-time binding. See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33480877/1889273

Answer (score 1):

You can store the initial value in a variable and then reuse it. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_kumar/cb2ronfb/)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
{{initialValue}}
<button ng-click="increase()">Increase</button>
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
    var app=angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
    var initialValue=20;
    $scope.initialValue=initialValue;
    $scope.reset=function(){
    $scope.initialValue=initialValue;
    };
    $scope.increase=function(){
    $scope.initialValue+=1;
    console.log('Increase value', $scope.initialValue);
    };
    });
```

Comment: it's ok but i want second question's answer. how do i get that value after increment

Comment: Edited the answer please check

Comment: can i access value of increase() globally  and how?

Comment: Please describe what you actually want. If you want to make something global then use `$rootScope`. You need to do something like this `$rootScope=initialValue`

Comment: `$rootScope.initialValue=initialValue`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114796/discussion-between-hitesh-kumar-and-ihemant360).

Answer (score 0):

You should hold a variable in your controller (constant is more appropriate) with which you will reset your `count` whenever you want.

***Controller***

```
$scope.initialValue = 23;
$scope.count = $scope.initialValue;

function resetCounter() {
    $scope.count = $scope.initialValue;
}
```

***Template***

```
<button ng-click = "count = count + 1"> Increase </button>

{{count}}

<button ng-click = "resetCounter()"> Reset </button>
```

Comment: give example ... it's not working . total angular .js disabled after doing this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "total angular.js disabled...". Anyway, show us your source code.

Comment: it means js file. and i did console.log() and error is `initialValue is not defined`

Comment: chanage your `$scope.count = initialValue;` to `$scope.count = $scope.initialValue;`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to $scope, working with TypeScript... :)

Answer (score 0):

Q1.My question is How do i reset that value to 23 and display ? OR store that value in a variable.

```
$scope.count = 23;  // this is the initial value
<button ng-click = "count = count + 1"> Increase</button>
<button ng-click = "count = 23"> Reset</button>
{{count}}   //Here Value will increase
```

Q2. Suppose count value increased from 23 to 29 by clicking. And how to get that value 29.

```
$scope.get = 0;
<button ng-click = "get = count"> Get</button>
{{get}}
```